# Приватная функция перекрывает публичный интерфейс базового класса

Tags: c++

Пример:

Подписчик:

```
class Subscriber {};
```

Базовый класс:

```
class SubscribableChannel
{
public:
    virtual ~SubscribableChannel() = default;

public:
    auto subscribe(Subscriber&) -> void;
    auto unsubscribe(Subscriber&) -> void;

private:
    virtual auto internal_subscribe(Subscriber&) -> void = 0;
    virtual auto internal_unsubscribe(Subscriber&) -> void = 0;
};

auto SubscribableChannel::subscribe(Subscriber& s) -> void
{ internal_subscribe(s); }

auto SubscribableChannel::unsubscribe(Subscriber& s) -> void
{ internal_unsubscribe(s); }
```

Класс-наследник `SubscribableChannel`:

```
class PubSubChannel : public SubscribableChannel
{
public:
    PubSubChannel() = default;

private:
    auto internal_subscribe(Subscriber&) -> void override {};
    auto internal_unsubscribe(Subscriber&) -> void override {};
    // Здесь появляется функция `unsubscribe`
    // имя которой совпадает с именем одной из функций базового класса,
    // но их сигнатуры отличаются: Subscriber& vs (Subscriber&, int)
    auto unsubscribe(Subscriber&, int) -> void {}
};
```

В результате попытка вызова функции `unsubscribe`:

```
PubSubChannel channel;
Subscriber s;
channel.unsubscribe(s);
```

, приводит к следующей ошибке:

> error: no matching function for call to ‘PubSubChannel::unsubscribe(Subscriber&)’
>
> note: candidate: ‘void PubSubChannel::unsubscribe(Subscriber&, int)’

Вопрос: является ли данное поведение допустимым? Если да - дайте, пожалуйста, линк на номер параграфа из [стандарта C++](http://eel.is/c++draft).

**ENV: linux, clang-10/gcc-10**

Comment: Все верно, функция-член с тем же именем скрывает функцию-член базового класса. Надо добавить `unsubscribe(Subscriber& s) { SubscribableChannel::unsubscribe(s);}`/ Ссылку на стандарт сейчас попробую найти...

Comment: @Harry, спасибо большое!

Comment: Впрочем, мое решение - до C++11, сейчас, если не ошибаюсь, можно использовать `using`... В стандарте все это описано в разделе *6.4.10 Name hiding* ([basic.scope.hiding]).

Comment: @Harry, спасибо, сейчас ознакомлюсь!

Comment: Точно, достаточно дописать в классе `PubSubChannel` строку `using SubscribableChannel::unsubscribe;` - см. строку 33 здесь: https://ideone.com/V4KTr7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это описывается в

> **11.8 Member name lookup [class.member.lookup]**
>   2 The following steps define the result of name lookup for a member name f in a class scope C.
>   3 The lookup set for f in C , called S ( f,C ), consists of two component sets: the declaration set, a set of members named f ; and the subobject set, a set of subobjects where declarations of these members (possibly including using-declarations) were found. In the declaration set, using-declarations are replaced by the set of designated members that are not hidden or overridden by members of the derived class (9.9), and type declarations (including injected-class-names) are replaced by the types they designate. S(f,C) is calculated as follows:
>   4 If C contains a declaration of the name f , the declaration set contains every declaration of f declared in C that satisfies the requirements of the language construct in which the lookup occurs.
>   [Note: Looking up a name in an elaborated-type-specifier (6.5.4) or base-specifier (11.7), for instance, ignores all non-type declarations, while looking up a name in a nested-name-specifier (6.5.3) ignores function, variable, and enumerator declarations. As another example, looking up a name in a using-declaration (9.9) includes the declaration of a class or enumeration that would ordinarily be hidden by another declaration of that name in the same scope. —end note]
>   If the resulting declaration set is not empty, the subobject set contains C itself, and calculation is complete.
>   5 Otherwise (i.e., C does not contain a declaration of f or the resulting declaration set is empty), S ( f,C ) is initially empty. If C has base classes, calculate the lookup set for f in each direct base class subobject B i ,
>   and merge each such lookup set S(f,B i ) in turn into S(f,C).

Так как  в `PubSubChannel`  есть объявление `unsubscribe`, то поиск в базовых классах не производится.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Скажите, правильно ли я понял, что в данном случае Derived::unsubscribe скрывает Base::unsubscribe _раньше_, чем перегружает ее?

Comment: Мне кажется, еще этот параграф может быть полезен: http://eel.is/c++draft/over.dcl#1. Если посчитаете нужным - добавьте, пожалуйста, в свой ответ.

Comment: `Derived::unsubscribe` ничего не перегружает, так как `Base::unsubscribe` находится в другой области видимости. А при вызове `channel.unsubscribe(s);` `Base::unsubscribe` не попадает в список перегрузок, так как имя `unsubscribe` находится объявленным в класса `Derived`, на чем поиск завершается.

Comment: Понял Вас, спасибо!